# No action on click for button in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm building a UI where a user can click on an item in an 'Options' list and add it to a 'Selected' list.

The items on the 'Selected' list have a remove button to send it back to the 'Options' list. I just can't get the remove button to work. I have limited the action of the remove button to a simple alert for troubleshooting purposes.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

PS. My question has been marked as a duplicate: Event binding on dynamically created elements? I have read that question and I'm trying to apply it. I'm looking for specific help on what I'm doing wrong in my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var a = [];
$(".remove").click(function(){
    alert("Remove Clicked");
});

$(".select").click(function(){
    var cList = $('ul.mylist');
    $('ul.mylist').empty();
    $('ui-menu-item').empty();
    a.push($(this).next("span").text());
    $(this).closest("li").hide();
    $( "#s" ).text( a.join( " " ));
    
    $.each(a, function(i){
     var li = $('<li/>')
            .addClass('ui-menu-item-'+a[i])
            .attr('role', 'menuitem')
            .appendTo(cList);
        var aaa = $('<a/>')
            .addClass('ui-all')
            .text(a[i])
            .appendTo(li);
        var $input = $('<button class="remove">Remove</button>');
            $input.prependTo($("li.ui-menu-item-"+a[i]));
   });
});   
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Selector</title>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>List of Options</h2>
<ul>
    <li><button class="select">Select</button><span>One</span></li>
    <li><button class="select">Select</button><span>Two</span></li>
    <li><button class="select">Select</button><span>Three</span></li>
    <li><button class="select">Select</button><span>Four</span></li>
</ul>
<h2>List of Selections</h2>
<ul class="mylist"> 
</ul>
<h3>Array of Selected Items to Sent to DB:</h3>
<span ID="s"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My question has been marked as a duplicate: Event binding on dynamically created elements? I have read that question and I'm trying to apply it. I'm looking for specific help on what I'm doing wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
    alert("Remove Clicked");
});
```

only adds the event handler to the buttons with class "remove" that exist at that time that the code is executed (after the page was loaded). It doesn't apply to buttons created after that.

Solution: add the function call to each button after you create it. Use a named function so you can reuse it.